# How to choose database for an ecommerce app

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, parse-platform

Hi I am new to mobile app development and want to make an ecommerce app in flutter. I am using firebase. But is it cost efficient what are the other alternative which is cheaper than firebase yet easy as firebase.
Also is parse server suitable for ecommerce app . I have seen the pricing for firebase and it seems soon my application will cross the free tier limit

Comment: try heruko or mongodb atlas

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend Amazon AWS for ecommerce app. Number of services like user authentication ( Cognito ), No Sql database( DynamoDB ), Api ( Api Gateway, Lambda function ) are available. Also free tier quota is great.